# C++ How to prevent Winapi::FreeLibrary removing a variable?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have a dll with lib.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef EXPORTS
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" API void test1(std::vector<ValueType*>* functions);
```

and lib.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "ValueType.h"
#include "NumberValue.h"

#include "TestLib.h"

void test1(std::vector<ValueType*>* functions) {
    functions->push_back(new NumberValue(123321));
```

And main file, that uses this dll is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>   

#include "ValueType.h"  

using namespace std;   

typedef void (__cdecl* importedInitFunction)(std::vector<ValueType*>*);
importedInitFunction test1F;

std::vector<ValueType*> values;   

int main() {
    while (1) {
        HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary("DllTest1.dll");  
        test1F = (importedInitFunction)GetProcAddress(lib, "test1");
        test1F(&values);
        FreeLibrary(lib);
        std::cout << values.at(0)->asString();
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to compile my code, I catch an error because `values.at(0)` is removed.
How to prevent deleting my variable when calling FreeLibrary(lib) ? or
How to implement alternative way ?

Another classes that used:
ValueType.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class ValueType {
public:


    virtual double asDouble() { return 999; }
    virtual std::string asString() { return ""; }


};
```

NumberValue.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "ValueType.h"

class NumberValue : public ValueType {
public:

    double m_value;

    NumberValue(double value) : m_value(value) {}

    virtual double asDouble() {
        return m_value;
    }

    virtual std::string asString() {
        return std::to_string(m_value);
    }
};
```

Comment: Pass a pointer to a function, to a function in .dll, from your main application, that will be used to create the object? When you `new` in a .dll, it is created in the memory space of the .dll.

Comment: how can i do a function in dll that will add "new NumberValue"  to my vector?

Comment: Re-read my comment. You can't, without changing the interface, in the manner, that I described.

Comment: Сan I somehow return the values ​​of C ++ types from the library?

Comment: Define what do you mean by "Сan I somehow return the values ​​of C ++ types from the library?".

Comment: Don't use extern "C", because when extern "C" used, i can't return c++ types of value (extern "C" std::vector<int> func1(); //error)

Comment: _"Сan I somehow return the values ​​of C ++ types from the library?"_ No, unfortunately you can't. Imagine the function in the DLL returns a vector filled with some values. The memory for the vector will be allocated by the DLL's `new`. Now you resize this vector from your main program, where the main program's `delete`/`new` will be used and as we are now in a different memory space bad things will happen.

Comment: I'm writing my own interpreter, and i want to create functionality for creating user's own functions, that are written in c++.  
can you offer any alternative to implement something like this?

Comment: Belaying the "memory space" lingo being tossed about, a few questions: are your DLL and EXE both built on the *same* runtime-usage settings (i.e. are they both compiling to code using the dynamic msvcrt runtime, as opposed to one being built for dynamic runtime, the other static ? Normally I discourage sending non-trivial objects in-general across DLL/EXE boundaries, but the question is important, so please look into that.

Comment: @VovaKosachev "_can you offer any alternative to implement something like this?_" I already told you the first solution that came to mind: provide a callback, that allocates the memory in the main process. Couldn't think of the possible signature of such a callback yet (given the hints of infrastructure, you have, in the question), but it would depend on the infrastructure, of classes you need to allocate.

Comment: Yes, settings are identical.

Comment: Can you elaborate. "settings are identical" doesn't mean much when we don't know what those settings *are*. On both, drilling into properties, "C++/Code Generation" , the "Runtime Library" setting is set to "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" for debug builds, and "Multi-threaded DLL" for release builds ? And just-as-important, you're loading debug and debug, not debug and release (or release and debug) builds respectively (hope that made sense).

Comment: @WhozCraig, "Runtime Library" already set correctly, and i use only debug in main app and in dll

Comment: Ok. last try: *What exactly is the Runtime Library setting for both your exe and your dll?* Are both  being built with  "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" for debug builds, and "Multi-threaded DLL" for release builds. Further, when testing, you're always running like-builds (i.e. if you're running the debug exe, its loading the debug dll) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, For debug builds i use "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" for both, and for release builds i use "Multi-threaded DLL" for both. I'm running test1.exe(Debug build) and trying to load DllTest1.dll(Debug build)

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll have to stand up a test jig, because that *should* have a decent shot at working. As I said before, I don't advise what you're doing in general just because the setup is so finicky, and I agree with Algirdas that a callback mechanic is probably a better idea, but now i'm super curious. Regardless, if everyone is using the same allocator (and they are, out of the active msvcrt in your process), things should line up. It's late here, so it may be awhile before I get to this, but I'll try to when time allows. Thx for providing the info requested.

Comment: DLLs don't have their own "memory space", what's happening is the DLL creates a memory heap, the vector is allocated on the DLL's heap and then when the DLL is unloaded the memory heap is freed. If you return objects from a DLL that need to be freed by the DLL you should increment the DLL's reference count to prevent it being unloaded prematurely. Obviously you can't do this with `std::vector` so you should wrap it in your own structure and provide a matching "Free()" function.

Comment: "I catch an error" is too vague.  What ought to happen is a hard crash on an AV, exception code 0xc0000005.  The FreeLibrary() call is dangerous, it unloads the code that implements the NumberValue class.  So anything you'd do with the object, including copying and destructing it, is going to take a nose-dive.  Just don't unload it, there is no compelling reason to do so.